# Closing InAppBrowser in Phonegap 2.9.0 is broken

Tags: android, cordova

I try to implement Google OAuth 2 authentication within a Phonegap 2.9.0 application. Based on this [blog post](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html), I managed to open the auth consent page, grab the code, post it to get the access token back. It works if I don't close the InAppBrowser window.

The issue is that when I call `authWindow.close()`, the following errors are shown in Eclipse LogCat:

```
08-11 07:54:10.588: I/Web Console(803): Close Windows at file:///android_asset/app/js/oauth2.js:121
08-11 07:54:10.648: I/Web Console(803): processMessage failed: Message: S11 InAppBrowser938825912 {"type":"loadstart","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/?code=4\/QxgCmz53B2eksAGCS8qsF.otg5rhswx00QOdsfdsfsdfl05ti8ZT3bTmXfagAI"} at file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:980
08-11 07:54:10.658: I/Web Console(803): processMessage failed: Error: Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:981
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803): processMessage failed: Stack: Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at androidExec (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:863:48)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at Object.close (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:3336:9)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at Object.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/app/js/oauth2.js:123:30)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at Object.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.js:4676:9)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at [object Object].<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.js:4360:28)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at [object Object].fire (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:709:23)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at Object._eventHandler (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:3332:39)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:3376:12
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at Object.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:301:54)
08-11 07:54:10.728: I/Web Console(803):     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:975:21) at file:///android_asset/app/js/lib/cordova.js:982
```

Authorize method:

```js
oauth2.authorize = function(options) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            // Build the OAuth consent page URL
            var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
                client_id: options.client_id,
                redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                response_type: 'code',
                scope: options.scope
            });

            // Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
            var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

            // The recommendation is to use the redirect_uri
            // "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
            // which sets the authorization code in the browser's title.
            // However, we can't
            // access the title of the InAppBrowser.
            //
            // Instead, we pass a bogus redirect_uri of "http://localhost",
            // which means the
            // authorization code will get set in the url. We can access the
            // url in the
            // loadstart and loadstop events. So if we bind the loadstart
            // event, we can
            // find the authorization code and close the InAppBrowser after
            // the user
            // has granted us access to their data.
            $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
                console.log('loadStart callback');
                var url = e.originalEvent.url;
                console.log(url);
                var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
                console.log('Code = ' + code);
                var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

                if (code) {
                console.log('process Code');
                    // Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                    $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                        code: code[1],
                        client_id: options.client_id,
                        client_secret: options.client_secret,
                        redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        console.log('DONE: ' + data);
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).fail(function(response) {
                        console.log('FAIL: ' + response);
                        deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                    });
                } else if (error) {
                    // The user denied access to the app
                    deferred.reject({
                        error: error[1]
                    });
                }

                if (code || error) {
                console.log('Close Windwos');
                    // Always close the browser when match is found
                    authWindow.close();
                }

                console.log("Fin loadStart");
            });

            return deferred.promise();
        };
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, do you have the same issue?

Comment: I had a related issue (I didn't check the logs though). My error was a `error with redirect_uri`. I changed my Google Api Console app from website to integrated app (Android) and everything is now working fine.